# @CollectionTable missing in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.2.3

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We are using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` 1.2.3 in our project for hibernate specific dependencies but I cannot find `@CollectionTable` annotation there. Do I need to include any other jar ?

Comment: spring-boot-sample-data-jpa version 1.0.2.RELEASE doesn't have it either. Does that help?

Comment: @Nicholas : What is the best way to store a List of Enums present with in an entity ? One to Many mapping ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It implies you are looking for an example of `@CollectionTable` in the spring-boot-start-data-jpa archetype. Instead, now you seem to be implying that you think it is not available. Please be clear with your questions. Of course `@CollectionTable` is available in JPA. As for your second question, just google it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998824/mapping-setenum-using-elementcollection

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. Secondly my question is what is the alternative of @CollectionTable. We have an entity containing List of enums, how to persist them (what should be the best table structure & which annotation to use now).

Comment: Hi Sahil. I think if you follow the link you will find what you are looking for.